# In triangle $ABC,$ we have $\angle B = 2\angle A.$ Prove that $b^2 = a(a+c).$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Here, I have a very interesting problem that I found.

> In triangle $ABC,$ we have $\angle B = 2\angle A.$ Prove that $b^2 =
> a(a+c).$

---

Here is how far I have gotten:

Here, $\angle B= 2 \angle A$ and therefore, $\angle C = 180- 3 \angle A$. Now, I use the Law of Cosines because if I distribute out the RHS of the equation we need to prove, we get $b^2 = a^2 + ac$, which is close to what I would get by the Law of Cosines.

If I use Law of Cosines, I get the following possibilities:
$$
a^2 = b^2+c^2 -2bc\cdot \cos A\\
\boxed{b^2 = a^2+c^2 -2ac\cdot \cos B} \\
c^2 = a^2+b^2 -2ab\cdot \cos C.$$
Now what would I do?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You have to find a way of using the condition you are given.

Comment: Thank you guys for redirecting me to the problem. I had searched, but was not able to find it. :)